# how to do Kafka syncing between two consumer groups

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

in my requirement I have two consumer group, one Group(Main) just take the data and send to other server, if sending to other server is failed then I need to rejoin(start) other consumer group(Failed processing)
.

In this case Main Group  continues to read and retry , and it will continue the same and some point when message sending become success it needs to notify other consumer group(Failed processing). Now Failed processing should start sending from where first fail to last fail.

```
public void StartMainstreamHandler() {
       StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> userStream = builder.stream("usertopic",Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "main-streams-userstream");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "ALL my bootstrap servers);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 4);
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "500");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        //consumer_timeout_ms
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 2000);

        props.put("state.dir","/tmp/kafka/stat));


   userStream.peek((key,value)->System.out.println("key :"+key+" value :"+value));
   /* Send Data to other Server if Failed call other consumer */

KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);


kafkaStreams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

                logger.error("Thread Name :" + t.getName() + " Error while processing:", e);
            }
        });


        kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
        kafkaStreams.start();
    }
```

Other Consumer

```
public void StartFailstreamHandler() {
       StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, String> userStream = builder.stream("usertopic",Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "failed-streams-userstream");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "ALL my bootstrap servers);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG, 4);
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "500");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        //consumer_timeout_ms
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 2000);

        props.put("state.dir","/tmp/kafka/stat));

     Wait('till get notfication from other consumer" ){
     userStream.peek((key,value)->System.out.println("key :"+key+" value :"+value));
     /* start sending */
     /* how to break when it is reached last offest */ 
   }

KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);


kafkaStreams.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {

                logger.error("Thread Name :" + t.getName() + " Error while processing:", e);
            }
        });


        kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
        kafkaStreams.start();
    }
```

Now How to know and sync the offset details at second consumer to exactly stop at last failed ( last failed happened at main consumer)

Comment: So you've essentially rewritten MirrorMaker with Kafka Streams?

Comment: actual goal is to retain the messages which are not successfully processed by one consumer group and that retained messages should be processed by other consumer group.

Comment: So you're making a dead-letter topic? Then why would you need to sync groups? The offsets are completely differernt

Comment: I was thinking that we need two consumer Group to keep the message in topic when once consumer is read , Later came to know that I can use retention period https://medium.com/@werneckpaiva/how-to-seek-kafka-consumer-offsets-by-timestamp-de351ba35c61
..  Now the question how  to know about two consumer which is reading latest and other reading from earliest (failed time stamp), I want to stop the other consumer when it reaches to main consumer where it data was processed-ed successfully

Comment: You need to store that information externally. Consumer groups have no way to coordinate with each other out of the box

Answer (score 1):

It's not reasonably possible to sync consumer groups between clusters with messages alone because there's not way for a consumer to seek to a particular "replicated start point".

You'd have to store extra metadata to the side such as timestamps that replication started, maybe embedding that information in the record headers (assuming your version of Kafka supports it}. Otherwise, you're more or less blindly copying data with minimal guarantees of delivery (and therefore might be better off using MirrorMaker anyway).

MirrorMaker 2 or Confluent Replicator are currently the only two options available for "syncing" of consumer groups, to make an active-active dual cluster setup

Comment: MM2 make syncing across two DC level.  even for across two consumer Group in same DC, is this the only way ?

Comment: Any suggestion on this proceed ?

Comment: I don't understand the question about "across two consumer Group in same DC". Why would you sync in the same DC instead of just having consumers all part of one group?

Comment: As I had mentioned, my service needs to read the data and send to some third party  servers, so sometimes that third party service goes down after their service is UP I need send the records which are latest and the records  where it was failed  simultaneously. so I went with this offest sync across consumer or groups.

Comment: Are you not able to store offsets in a database? Why do they need to just be in a consumer group if not actually used by another kafka consumer? Also, I don't think kafka streams exposes that offset information anyway